# таймер на промисах

Tags: promise

решил написать простенький сайт, основная функция которого - таймер. Возникла проблема с работой таймера. Что может быть не так?

```js
 let time = Number(document.getElementById("1".value));

      let timer = (time) =>
        new Promise((resolve, time) =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
          }, time * 1000)
        );

      let timer1 = async () => {
        let begintime = "Запущено";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = begintime;
        await timer();
        let endtime = `Таймер на ${time} секунд завершил свою работу`;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = endtime;
      };
```

```html
       <input
          id="1"
        />
       <button
            onclick="timer1()"
            type="button"
          >
            Запустить
          </button>

        <textarea
          readonly
          id="result"
        ></textarea>
        <label></label>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: скобку перенесите перед .value в первой строке

Comment: скобку перенес, это была мелкая ошибка, переписал немного код, стал запускаться, но теперь не читается значения времени и промис по умолчанию выполняется с time = 0

Answer (score 0):

В коде есть несколько ошибок:

1. неверно расставлены скобки в строке: `let time = Number(document.getElementById("1".value));`. Для решения достаточно перенести скобку перед `.value`: `let time = Number(document.getElementById("1").value);`
2. неверно используется [конструктор Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise). Функция передаваемая в конструктор принимает два параметра: `resolve` - функция успешно завершающая Promise, и `reject` - функция завершающая Promise в состояние `reject`. В коде в вопросе, для второй функции выбрано имя `time`, и она передается в качестве параметра `time * 1000` - из-за этого время срабатывания кажется неожиданным.
3. использование одного и того же имени для переменных, и параметров функций. Это приводит к тому, что тяжело понять где переменная, а где параметр, что приводит к неожиданным результатам
4. функция `timer` вызывается без параметра, а значит значение ее аргумента `undefined`, что неверное, даже несмотря на то, что он нигде не используется.
5. значения из `input` забирается в самом начале - когда оно еще не задано. Для решения достаточно перенести этот код внутрь функции `timer1`.

Пример:

```js
let timer = (time) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, time * 1000)
  );

let timer1 = async() => {
  let time = Number(document.getElementById("1").value);

  let begintime = "Запущено";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = begintime;
  await timer(time);
  let endtime = `Таймер на ${time} секунд завершил свою работу`;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = endtime;
};
```

```html
<input id="1" />
<button onclick="timer1()" type="button">Запустить</button>

<textarea readonly id="result"></textarea>
<label></label>
```